# How to dissect the functionality of a PPA?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, apt, ppa

I'd like to understand how PPAs such as this work that display a license:
[Oracle Java (JDK) 8 / 9 Installer PPA | launchpad.net](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java)

Where do you get started in tracing through how this works?  Is there a source file similar to Homebrew formulae that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

The license isn’t displayed by the PPA, but by the packages which you install from it. For example, installing `oracle-java9-installer` will unpack a number of maintainer scripts into `/var/lib/dpkg/info`, one of which, `preinst`, is run before the package is installed. This script displays information about the license and asks the user to accept or decline it. You can see its contents (and the contents of all the others) by downloading [the package’s source code](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java/+files/oracle-java9-installer_9.0.4-1~webupd8~0.tar.xz) and looking in the `jdk9-installer/debian` directory. The `preinst` script is `oracle-java9-installer.preinst` there, and the templates which are used to display the questions are in `oracle-java9-installer.templates`.